# Spring cookie locale resolver forgets selected locale when 'defaultlocale' provided

Tags: java, spring, localization

I have created custom `@Controller` that ivokes language change in Spring 3:

```
 RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver( request )
    .setLocale( request , response , [some special-way choosen locale] );
```

This works fine with select-request and any further request only if I dont set attribute **defaultlocale** in Spring `CookieLocaleResolver` resolver:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieName" value="clientlanguage" />
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="60000" />
        <property name="cookiePath" value="/" />
</bean>
```

**The problem is that I want to avoid locale auto-detection**, so I provide default locale:

```
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_EN" />
```

Adding this property causes that **locale is always en_EN**, and i can't change it. Even first request to locale-chage controller is rendered with english bundle.

I looked up to HTTP response in laguage change and I get just:

`Set-Cookie: clientlanguage=""; ....`

Comment: Is en_EN valid? I cant find it in ISO 3166( valid country codes). http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html

Comment: What is the version of your spring-webmvc jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I was setting "pl_PL" locale instead of just "pl". With "pl_PL" the cookie was set to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Well accoring to Spring documentation, when you specify the default locale, if no cooki is found, then the default locale is used [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.html#setDefaultLocale%28java.util.Locale%29)
So I guess that in tests you did, no cookie is sent; what I would suggest you is to use an interceptor; you can check the request and check for cookies; if no cookie is found, you can use your default locale; did you try to use interceptors?

Answer (score 0):

The various methods of `CookieLocaleResolver` which use the `defaultLocale` use it like so

```
request.setAttribute(LOCALE_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
        (locale != null ? locale: determineDefaultLocale(request)));
```

In other words, it only uses the `defaultLocale` if an actual `Locale` cannot be resolved from the cookies. This is inline with what the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.html#setDefaultLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) says

> Set a fixed `Locale` that this resolver will return if no cookie found.

You states

> Adding this property causes that locale is always en_EN

It will only be `en_EN` if you either didn't provide a cookie with the `Locale` or if your

```
RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver( request )
                   .setLocale( request , response , [some special-way choosen locale] );
```

invocation was made with a `null` `Locale` argument.